# How do I get a badge for a specific release deployment?

Tags: azure-devops

You can get a badge for the release pipeline itself which always shows the status of the most recent deployment, like `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/public/Release/badge/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227/1/5`.

How do you get one for a specific deployment, not just the most recent deployment?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no such method could get the badge for a specific release deployment.

Based on my test, the release badge only supports selecting the release stage, and displays the latest deployment status in the stage.

From the URL:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/public/Release/badge/4adb1680-0eac-6149-b5ee-fc8b4f6ca227/1/5
```

**1** represents the **Release Definitionid**， **5** represents the **Stage environmentId**.

Therefore, he has no way to specify a specific deployment for the time being.

But this requirement is reasonable.

Here is a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/728341/badge-image-showing-the-deployed-version-of-each-s.html) with the similar requirement, you can vote in the suggestion ticket and add comments to express your thoughts